# How to access the dict value?

Tags: python

I have a response syntax of type `dict`:

```
{
    'StoppingInstances': [
        {
            'InstanceId': 'string',
            'CurrentState': {
                'Code': 123,
                'Name': 'pending'|'running'|'shutting-down'|'terminated'|'stopping'|'stopped'
            },
            'PreviousState': {
                'Code': 123,
                'Name': 'pending'|'running'|'shutting-down'|'terminated'|'stopping'|'stopped'
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Now if I need to check if the currentState is `stopping` how to do so?

```
print "Stopping instance Now",response['StoppingInstances']

for instance in response['StoppingInstances']:
    if instance['CurrentState']['Name'] == "stopping":
        print "Still Stooping"

    if instance['CurrentState']['Name'] == "stopped":
        print "Instance Stopped"
print "Now Starting the instance"
response_new = client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
for start_instance in response_new['StartingInstances']:
    if start_instance['CurrentState']['Name'] == "running":
        print "Instance is UP and running"
    else:
        print "Some Error occured!!"
```

Comment: Just look at your data. `response['StoppingInstances']` is a list (array, in JSON), you need to index it with an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `response['StoppingInstances']` object is a *list* of dictionaries. You'd have to either loop over those or index an individual item:

```
response['StoppingInstances'][0]['CurrentState']['Name'] == "stopping"
```

If you need to test if *any* of those objects is in the `stopping` state, you could use the `any()` function:

```
any(o['CurrentState']['Name'] == "stopping" for o in response['StoppingInstances'])
```

If you need to test each instance, use a loop:

```
for instance in response['StoppingInstances']:
    if instance['CurrentState']['Name'] == "stopping":
```

Comment: how is it determined that it is a list of dict ?

Comment: @DrugLORD: look closely at the syntax. You have a `[....]` list, containing one `{...}` dictionary. The name of the key is also a hint; it is `StoppingInstances`, *plural*, not `StoppingInstance`, singular.

Comment: oh okay, i am actually trying to stop and start the instances one by one, i am updating the code, can you please take a look

Comment: @DrugLORD: then use a `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, I saw. I already updated my answer. Sorry, I can't keep updating for every twist plot; stick to a clear question and you'll get clear answers, then ask *new* questions about new problems you encounter.

Comment: Thanks i will ask a new question and paste the link here at comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data contains a list enclosing the outer dict values, and not simple nested dictionaries as you suppose. You need to index the list, then access the nested dict values via the keys:

```
response['StoppingInstances'][0]['CurrentState']['Name']
#                             ^
```

And in your `if` block:

```
if response['StoppingInstances'][0]['CurrentState']['Name'] == "stopped":
     print "Instance Stopped"
```

Comment: how can i know more about dict ??

Comment: @DrugLORD There are lots of good online tutorials  like [this one](http://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php) but your first reference should be the [python docs on data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Thank you Moses , I  have updated the new code, can you take a look ?

Comment: @DrugLORD Is the code not working? You can describe the error(s) you have, if any, in the post.

Comment: actually i think i placed the if condition wrongly , it tries to start the instance while it is still being stopped .
`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IncorrectInstanceState) when calling the StartInstances operation: The instance 'i-897da234' is not in a state from which it can be started.
`

Comment: @DrugLORD I haven't used `boto`, but I think if you run a `while` loop that will only break when the instance is stopped, you can keep track of when exactly an instance has stopped, and then try to start it.

Comment: I tried `for instance in response['StoppingInstances']:
        while instance['CurrentState']['Name'] != "stopped":
            print "Still Stoping"` But this gets stuck to infinity